# Convert List to Matrix (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, matrix

I'm trying to convert a list to an array (list of lists) from a function that receives an Int (i) that is a counter that always starts at 0, another Int (n) that is the length of each row and the list that I have to convert to matrix.

```
createMatrix :: (Int, Int, [Int]) -> [[Int]]
createMatrix (i, n, ([])) = []
createMatrix (i, n, (x:y)) = if (i < n) then [x] : createMatrix (i+1, n, (y))
                            else  [] ++ createMatrix (0, n, (x:y))
```

This gives me as output:

```
[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18]]
```

when it should be something like:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16,17,18]]
```

in case n is 6

Does anyone have an idea that I may be failing? I tried several things and found no solution.

Thanks

Comment: Something like `createMatrix n xs = take n xs : createMatrix n (drop n xs)` would suffice. You don't need two counters; the other counter is internal to `take` and `drop`.

Comment: Hey! Thanks but I have to solve it without using take and drop!

Comment: The answer is somewhat shortened. Complete with a first line: `createMatrix _ [] = []` and then `createMatrix n xs = take n xs : createMatrix n (drop n xs)`.

Answer (score 2):

You're always adding an entire new list to your output when you write `[x]:createMatrix (...)`. And when you do `[] ++ createMatrix (...)`, you aren't doing anything to your result; `concat`ing an empty list does nothing.

You want to prepend `x` to the first list in the result of `createMatrix (...)`, instead of prepending `[x]` to the entire result.

In the `else` case, you want to prepend a new empty list, rather than trying to use `++`, which concatenates two lists.

Comment: Something like this? createMatrix (i, n, (x:y)) = if (i < n) then x : createMatrix (i+1, n, (y)) else [] : createMatrix (0, n, (x:y))

Comment: So in this case, you're adding prepending both x and [] to the beginning of the result list. IF haskell supported heterogeneous lists, you would end up with: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,[],7,8,9,10,11,12,[],13,14,15,16,17,18,[]]`, but it doesn't, so this will type error. You need to get the first list out of the recursive result, add x to it, and put it back into the result.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution that does without the `counter` and simply splits your list every given `n`:

```
matrixEvery :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
matrixEvery _ [] = []
matrixEvery n xs = as : matrixEvery n bs
  where (as,bs) = matrixEvery n xs
```

Recursion is being used instead of passing around a counter.
The only downfall is you if you want to make your matrices all of equal sizes this won't work but get's you closer :)

Comment: GHC 9.0.2 did not work with this solution. I guess missing a `take n` somewhere.